# How to use get_posts to filter against a single post id?

Tags: get-posts

How do I use get_posts to filter against a single post id?  (I don't want to use get_post because am using this in another function that could take other parameters and should return an array).  The following methods are not working:

```
get_posts(array(
    'ID' => 12345,
));

get_posts(array(
    'p' => 12345,
));

get_posts(array(
    'post' => 12345,
));

get_posts(array(
    'post__in' => array(12345),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, all of these methods work if I add the post_type parameter to the query:

```
get_posts(array(
    'ID' => 12345,
    'post_type' => array('any'),
));

get_posts(array(
    'p' => 12345,
    'post_type' => array('any'),
));

get_posts(array(
    'post' => 12345,
    'post_type' => array('any'),
));

get_posts(array(
    'post__in' => array(12345),
    'post_type' => array('any'),
));
```

This is a really stupid design decision; any post type should be assumed if the parameter is omitted.